# Connect External MySQL Server from Cloud 9 via Python

Tags: python, mysql, cloud9-ide

I am running the code below in **Cloud 9 IDE**, which is a snippet auto-generated from ipage. It just returns "Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'curdb.ipagemysql.com' (111)".

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

try:
  conn = MySQLdb.connect (
  host = "ipageusername.ipagemysql.com",
  user = "currentUser",
  passwd = "password",
  db = "curdb")

except MySQLdb.Error, e:
 print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
 sys.exit (1)

print "connected to the database"
```

Comment: does the server allows remote connections? is your computer in the allowance list? have you successfully connected with other clients besides python?

Comment: I could not find any mention of it saying I couldn't, however I also couldn't find anything referencing external database connections.